# Join and Fetch and reducing data returned

Tags: hibernate, join, hql, fetch

So i have a query that does multiple joins with other tables. I get a 904 error when returned because it is returning too many columns of data. I am also using "Join fetch" as well.

I read that using "Join" without "Fetch" will return the main table instead of everything. My question is that

1. will i be able to access subsequent table data since it is not returned with Join vs Join Fetch?  and
2. is there a way to reduce the columns i need (say i only need 5 out of 100) while the data still map to hibernate object (i read it becomes a list?).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, by lazy-loading them
2. yes, but you'll get a `List<Object[]>`, where each array contains the 5 selected properties. Returning entities in that case would make no sense: all the invariants of the returned objects would be violated since almost all their fields would be null.

Comment: So given my scenario where i dont want to get every single column back which causes the 904 AND wanting to keep my Hibernate mapping ("default/null" values are OK on unneeded columns), what is the best approach?    I also read that i can set the lazy loading property on the property in the mapping file : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-initialization  on 20.1.8 - is that another route?   I am querying tables with 100+ columns and dont need it all.. thanks

Comment: also from the link it mentions projection too... but that is only done in java not if i bring in an HQL right?

Comment: The best approach is to give up on your idea of getting back entities with null values inside.

Comment: so what are the best choices? not use Fetch for lazy loading at the table level and maybe use lazy loading at the properties level? will this prevent 904?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say how reduce without a code example, but I can explain the theory of this problem.

Every database has some limit of columns returned on a single query. I already dealed with this problem on a legacy application using SQL Server and Hibernate. This problem started to happen after upgrade the SLQ Server version.

There are some ways to resolve this problem. Maybe the legacy application had a lot of EAGER loading mapped on the entities, like:

```
@ManyToOne
private Person person;
```

(every `*ToOne` relationship are, by default, `EAGER`)

And this relationship have other `EAGER` relationships (`person` can eager load a `address`, `address` can eager load a `street`, etc). This scenario can bring a lot of unnecessary informations (columns) by `EAGER` loading.

The solution was identify some "branch" relationship that returns a lot of `EAGER` entities and "cut" it, using the lazy fetch:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Person person;
```

You need to identify, after this change, how this will affect your application, because the person information (and the other possible EAGER entities that person carries) is not anymore always available. This normally results on lazy exceptions, that you can deal getting the information inside a transaction or doing the query with `FETCH` word:

```
select order FROM Order order JOIN FETCH order.person
```

If you abuse the use of JPQL and `FETCH` on the same query, you can also have this problem of too many columns. But generally the database is very generous about this maximum number of columns, so this problem is way more common on bad entity relationships using EAGER everywhere. To cause this problem on a JPQL/Criteria query with `FETCH` word, this needs be a huge query.

After this explanation, I will anwser your questions:

> 1. will i be able to access subsequent table data since it is not returned with Join vs Join Fetch?

Yes. Inside a transaction you can lazy load the information, like:

```
Person person = order.getPerson();
```

> 2. is there a way to reduce the columns i need (say i only need 5 out of 100) while the data still map to hibernate object (i read it becomes a list?)

Yes. Removing EAGERs, not using `FETCH` on the JPQL query or [using tuples, DTOs or Object array](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-projection-query-to-a-dto-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).